# How to use FilerImageField in html template?

Tags: django

I want to know how to use FilerImageField in html tag. i tried

`<image src={{ instance.team_background_image_1.file.url }}>`

it display full image. but i want to use FilerImageField in many resolutions such as 300x300, 250x300

Comment: <img src='{{ instance.team_background_image_1.file.url }}' style="height:300px; width:300px">

Answer (score 0):

you have to use [easy_thumbnails](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails) for that and can use as follows

```
{% load thumbnail %}
{% thumbnail model_name.image_field 250x250 crop %}
```

read more [here](https://django-filer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)